Expo,React Native Error: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered, ReferenceError: Property 'user' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
I'm using on React Native and Expo go.
This error suddenly occurred while working as usual with React Native.
I don't remember exactly what step it was, but it seems to have started to occur after I created a hook called useProductFetch for useState variables or functions declared inside a functional component.
To solve this problem, I created a new project folder, moved the files, and reinstalled the dependencies. But I've been getting this error repeatedly, and I've been looking for a way to fix this for about two days. And to solve the error "Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered", i checked my "name" in app.json and package.json. there were not any problems.
Here is my codes.
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.7.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.5.5",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.9.2",
    "expo-radio-button": "^1.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


This is the part where a custom hook was used in the aforementioned component.

import { useProductFetch } from './useProductFetch';
import { primary_gray } from '../../styles/common/colors';
import { TouchMenu } from './touch_menu';
import { CreateReview } from './CreateReview';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export const ProductDetail = () => {
  const {
    currentPage,
    currentProduct,
    handleHeart,
    handleHorizontalScroll,
    heart,
    isUsers,
    token,
    user,
    borderWidths,
    handlePress,
    activeMenu,
    navigation,
  } = useProductFetch();
//...
...//
}

And the custom hook code:
export const useProductFetch = () => {
    const [heart, setHeart] = useState({});
    const { selectedProductId, currentProduct } = useSelector((state) => state.products);
    const [isUsers, setIsUsers] = useState(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { user, token } = useSelector((state) => state.userAuth);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(0);
    const borderWidths = [...Array(3)].map(() => useSharedValue(0));
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const handleHorizontalScroll = (event) => {
    const contentOffsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const currentPageIndex = Math.round(contentOffsetX / width);
    setCurrentPage(currentPageIndex);
  };

    const fetchDetail = useCallback(() => {
       if (selectedProductId) {
       try {
         dispatch(findProduct({ product_id: selectedProductId }));
         if (token) {
           ProductApi.isUsersProduct(token, selectedProductId).then((response) => {
             setIsUsers(response.data);
           });
         }
       } catch (error) {
         if (error.response) {
           switch (error.response.status) {
             case 400:
             case 500:
               navigation.navigate('Home');
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }, [selectedProductId]);

   useEffect(() => {
     borderWidths[activeMenu].value = withTiming(3, { duration: 500 });
   }, []);

   const handlePress = (index) => {
     setActiveMenu(index);
     borderWidths[index].value = withTiming(3, { duration: 500 });
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchDetail();
   },  [fetchDetail]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentProduct) {
      if (token && user) {
        if (currentProduct.likedBy.length > 0) {
          const isLiked = currentProduct.likedBy.some((val) => val.userId === user.id);
          setHeart((prevHeart) => ({
            ...prevHeart,
            [currentProduct.id]: isLiked,
          }));
        } else
          setHeart((prevHeart) => ({
            ...prevHeart,
            [currentProduct.id]: false,
          }));
      }
    }
  }, [currentProduct]);

  const handleHeart = () => {
    if (token && user && currentProduct) {
      setHeart((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [currentProduct.id]: !heart[currentProduct.id] }));
      const data = { [currentProduct.id]: !heart[currentProduct.id] };
      try {
        dispatch(updateProductLike({ token, likes: data }));
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          switch (error.response.status) {
            case 400:
            case 401:
            case 500:
              navigation.navigate('Home');
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert('로그인이 필요합니다');
      navigation.navigate('Login');
      return;
    }
  };

  return {
    currentProduct,
    currentPage,
    handleHeart,
    handleHorizontalScroll,
    heart,
    isUsers,
    handlePress,
    borderWidths,
    activeMenu,
    navigation,
    user,
    token,
  };
};

If there are no problems with the above code, I would guess that there may be a compatibility issue with the installed dependencies. I haven't posted many questions on StackOverflow, so please understand my awkwardness.
I want to solve the problem quickly and focus on coding.

I think you should check MainActivity of your app (located in android/app/src/main/java/your-package/MainActivity
check getMainComponentName name is the same

Do I need to check for Android even though I'm trying to build IOS? Or is this something that needs to be checked regardless of the OS being used? And does that path mean the expo repository in node_modules...?

Sorry i don't know for ios, but i got this error in android a time ago, and i fixed that in checking native files.

The cause lies elsewhere, and seems to be a problem with expo go's compiler. Thank you for helping!
